# Discount code - Order total amount does not match the Barclaycard ePDQ gross total amount

Tags: checkout, error, discount

Magento 1.7.2
I have setup 10% discount code for some products.

If someone use the 10% discount code at the checkout I have been receiving an error from my bank:

**"Order total amount does not match the Barclaycard ePDQ gross total amount"**

No discount code = no problem.

Could you please advise?